# How to import javascript file from public folder to SRC folder and use the function of that file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using topol.io email builder in ReactJS. i tried putting there plugin script inside src folder. But it was not working. Then i tried to put that file in public folder then it worked. Now i want to use the function of that JavaScript file in reactjs app.

How can i use that file's function. Or is there any way i can use that plugin folder inside my src directory.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "/static/topol.js";
    script.async = false;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

this is how i am using it now.

Comment: Do you use create-react-app ?

Comment: yes i am using that

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) your file. This will include it in the bundle, and you'll be able to use the functions defined in it.

Be aware that your ability to use a function defined in this file will depend on the way the function is exposed and declared.

Comment: this is the error i am getting while import. "You attempted to import ../../../../public/static/topol.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported."